# Running rails with webrick in debian vm need domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, webrick

I'm running a debian vm and inside there, there runs my rails application on a webrick server.

the default domain is lvh.me .. it comes out of the box from webrick I thought. Is there I possibility to change the lvh.me? so that I can run two virtual machines on my desktop? and can acces one with lvh.me and the second one with blubb.me or something like that?

Comment: lvh.me isn't a webrick thing.  It's a public redirect that points to localhost, so you can have the benefits of a fully qualified domain name even on a local system with no domain. You can also access your application by visiting the IP address of your VM plus your port. .. e.g.  192.168.2.45:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any number of domain names and force them to resolve to specific IP's in your `\etc\hosts` file.

Add something like this to your `\etc\hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 lvh.me
127.0.0.1 blubb.me
```

Comment: What error? Did you edit system hosts file or the one in apache?

Comment: Please add apache error traceback message to your question.